# How to fetch unpaid bills month in datagridview?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, datagridview, datetimepicker

i am new .net learner and i am trying to fetch unpaid bill months in datagridview2 from datagridview1.

suppose, one person bills are there based on months, like January to October as paid months and November ,December both as unpaid months.

so when i search name of customer then datagridview1 is displayed January to October as paid months but How to other two unpaid months name fetch in datagridview2 ??

using query i am able to fetch paid months from database for datagridview1 and for datagridview2,

here i have add 12 month first as string like,

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim month(12) As String
    month(0) = "January"
    month(1) = "February"
    month(2) = "March"
    month(3) = "April"
    month(4) = "May"
    month(5) = "June"
    month(6) = "July"
    month(7) = "August"
    month(8) = "September"
    month(9) = "October"
    month(10) = "November"
    month(11) = "December"
```

and then

create a column for datagridview2, which is fetch the new rows like November and December.

how can i fetch remain two months in datagridview2??

Answer (score 0):

Add a Dates table to your database (one row for each date, and add a column for year, month, quarter, fiscal year, fiscal month, etc.).

Outer join from that table to your transactions and, in your case, group on Month from the Date table (aka Date Dimension for data warehousing).